# Tooltips style in google charts

Tags: css, charts, tooltip

I would like to know if it is possible to change the font color of DEFAULT tooltips in a google line chart.

I want to do this by changing css style like this:

```
<style>

    .google-visualization-tooltip { 

            width: 150px !important;
            border: none !important;
            border-radius: 21px !important;
            background-color: rgb(30, 50, 230)!important;
            position: absolute !important;
            box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75) !important;
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%) !important;
            background: -webkit-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%) !important;
            background: -o-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%) !important;
            background: -ms-linear-gradient(30deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%) !important;
            background: linear-gradient(120deg, rgb(30, 50, 230) 30%, rgb(90, 140, 250) 70%) !important;
            font-size:  10px !important;

          }


    </style>
```

All of this css lines work well but I have not found the font color param until now.

By the way, if I modify "tooltip.textStyle" param of [Line Chart API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart) the font color changes but the CSS code mentioned above become unusable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it!

I needed to insert this lines in style tag.

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip > ul > li > span {
color: #ff0000 !important;
```

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the answer given from the same user that asked...

You will have to set

```
tooltip: { isHtml: true }
```

at the chart options for the CSS to work.
Please read the official Google Charts documentation: [customizing tooltip content](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_tooltip_content)

Answer (score 7):

Summing up the answers given by people above. :)

Enable the tooltip to be handled by the HTML by writing this code in your options of google charts CODE: `tooltip: { isHtml: true } (,)` add a comma if needed. :)

Now you can style tooltip using HTML and css. :)

/CSS Styling/

To style the tooltip box :

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip {}
```

To style the content like font size, color, etc

```
div.google-visualization-tooltip > ul > li > span {}
```

Use `!important` whenever needed ;)

Answer (score 5):

There is CSS file loaded by current version of charts:

https://www.gstatic.com/charts/45.1/css/core/tooltip.css

In this file you can see what styles were written by Google developers and just overwrite with your own. *Add !important if doesn't work*. Sample:

```
.google-visualization-tooltip {
  border:none !important;
}
```

And just load your custom css as any other css.

**How get current version of CSS file?**

You can get up to date version in chrome's network tab. Open developer tools (e.g. right click on any html object and select "inspect")

[image]